# Why does discoverAndAddAccount method of the API Explorer return a General IO Error?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

Calling the **discoverAndAddAccount** method via the **API Explorer** returns the following error:

`HTTP Status 500 - message=General IO error while proxying request; errorCode=006003; statusCode=500`.

Can anybody help me identify what I missed?

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue with the V3 API for IPP

Answer (score 1):

Did you pass the private key password and SSL key of certificate in the API explorer?

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/007_firstrequest

Comment: Yes, the getInstitutions and getInstitutionDetails methods work for me but the others do not.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify if you are passing a correct request body

```
<InstitutionLogin xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/fdatafeed/institutionlogin/v1">
    <credentials>
        <credential>
            <name>Banking Userid</name>
            <value>direct</value>
        </credential>
        <credential>
            <name>Banking Password</name>
            <value>anyvalue</value>
        </credential>
    </credentials>
</InstitutionLogin>
```

Doc Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0020_api_documentation/0020_discoverandaddaccounts#Discover_and_Add_Request

Also refer the following doc for correct userid and pwd while testing with dummy CC_Bank>

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/testing_calls_to_the_api

If it doesn't resolve the issue, then please raise a support ticket.

Link - http://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incident

Thanks

**EDIT** { Adding Snapshot }

[image]

'DiscoverAndAddAccounts' call is working fine for me. Can you share the screenshot. I can look into this and let u know if I get something.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Manas! I tried running the method on the dummy CC Bank also. Though it does not work (same error) on the API Explorer, I am able to proceed using the .NET SDK for this bank alone. For all others, same issue.

Comment: @bharathitm I've added a snapshot in my original post. Plz check

Comment: Hey Manas, thanks a ton for looking into this. I am not able to attach the screen shots as I dont have enough reputation points. Please find the image at - http://54.242.24.106/WSerror.png

Comment: can you share the request body here ? are you able to use other endpoints with your OAuth credentials ?